# Jmeter script for Infinispan distributed mode using hot rod

Tags: jmeter, infinispan

I am new to Jmeter. I have requirement for run load test for Infinispan distributed mode using hot rod client server on Jmeter.I have Infinispan clusted server available and running using some application. Please someone guide me to write Jmeter script for this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Mahesh Bubanale

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you shouldn't be testing Infinispan itself, I believe that it's tested by other people and considered reliable. My expectation is that you need to test an application, which is using Infinispan to implement some clustering functionality. If so and your application is web-based you can use JMeter to produce load and insert some assertions into your code to check that your test data is being correctly replicated. The best way to start with web application testing is recording your test script via [JMeter HTTP Proxy server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-superpower-http-proxy-server).

If I'm getting you wrong and you need to explicitly test Infinispan HotRod endpoint,  JMeter doesn't support HotRod protocol out of box. You'll need to get relevant libraries (.jar files) which implement [org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.protocol](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Data_Grid/6/html/API_Documentation/files/api/org/infinispan/client/hotrod/impl/protocol/package-summary.html) with dependencies, drop them to /lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation and after that do one of following:

1. Develop a custom JMeter Sampler containing protocol implementation details, arguments, entrance and exit criteria, etc.
2. Create a [Java Request similar](http://newspaint.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/creating-a-java-sampler-for-jmeter/) to option 1
3. Use BeanShell samplers to represent your test cases.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load test Infinispan Hot Rod server, you can use some Grinder scripts I created a while back. We've got some instructions [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/6.0.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#sid-68355066) but they're a bit outdated. Maybe you can help us update them and convert them to talking to Infinispan Server distribution and update to version 6.0? :)

Otherwise, if you want to test Infinispan embedded/library mode, we've [RadarGun](https://github.com/radargun/radargun) which is a benchmarking framework for data grids.